# SSIS - Deployed package SQL Command validation error

Tags: ms-access, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have created a SSIS package in order to transfer datas from ACCESS to SQL SERVER.

> **Source**  > SQL Command from "mdb" file joinning two tables
>
> **Destination** > Flat table in SQL Server

I'm performing the JOIN in the source SQL Command because of the number of records in the ACCESS tables (~500k).
I tried to use SSIS join but it take ages doing the ORDERING before JOIN.

While running package in VS2010, ***it works great***.

But after deploying and executing the package on my SQL Server 2014 the following error occurs.

```
No column information was returned by the SQL command.
Returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA"."
```

I'm pretty sure my SQL command is correct (Working in VS and the preview button in the editor show me records).

I tried to disable ValidateMetadata but the same error still occurs, but at execution this time.

In the SQL Server 2014 I have other packages calling ACCESS data (But without join) and it works properly.

Thanks for your help,

Q.

Answer (score 0):

ValidateMetadata is (generally) a good thing.

This error is being caused by the metadata on your source or destination (it's unclear from your question) being different.

At a guess, at least one of the columns in your SQL2014 database is of a different datatype (or length, or is nullable etc.) - there is a difference either way.